# Liferay showing HotDeployment and ClassCast Exception

Tags: java, liferay

I am getting the following error while building project in 
Liferay

> Antjava.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model.impl.GuestbookImpl cannot be cast to
>   com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model.Guestbook    at
>   com.liferay.docs.guestbook.service.persistence.GuestbookPersistenceImpl.findByGroupId(GuestbookPersistenceImpl.java:1541)
>     at
>   com.liferay.docs.guestbook.service.persistence.GuestbookPersistenceImpl.findByGroupId(GuestbookPersistenceImpl.java:1483)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you get a `ClassCastException` that a class can't be typecasted to its legitimate superclass or interface, you have duplicate code on your classpath - in this case most likely `Guestbook` is the culprit that you can find twice. Search your code, `WEB-INF/classes` folder and jars in `WEB-INF/lib`. And make sure you haven't added anything containing `Guestbook` to the global classpath

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using the below mentioned 2 ways:

While deploying the portlets that throws the class cast exception, do the following:

```
1.deploy the application in the liferay/deploy.
2.shutdown the liferay
3.move the service jar from the WEB-INF/lib from the portlet to the /lib/ext of the tomcat
4.remove the temp and work folder from the tomcat
5.restart the tomcat.
```

OR ...what worked for me was

```
change the package name while building the service.xml in the service.xml file
```

Or if you have already built the service, do these steps

`1.Just delete the 5 packages that are created from the service builder,` i.e

```
model.impl

service.base

service.http

service.impl

service.persistence

2.delete the .xml generated in the META-INF folder except for the file ext-spring.xml

3.delete the XX-service.jar from the docroot/lib folder.

4.delete the service folder in the docroot folder.

5.change the package name in the service.xml and build the path.
```